# How to calculate joint probabilities involving multiple variables?

Tags: probability, bayesian, bayesian-networks, probability-theory

Suppose we have events `A`, `B`, and `C`. We know `P(A)`, `P(B|A)`, and `P(C|B)`. How to calculate `P(ABC)`? I am familiar with Bayes' theorem.

Answer (score 0):

`P(ABC) = P(BC | A)P(A) = P(C | AB)P(B | A)P(A)`

This is true in general, regardless of the independence structure of `ABC`.

*A* way you could compute your desired joint distribution is if you had conditional independence of `C` and `A` given `B`, i.e. `P(C | AB) = P(C | B)`. Otherwise, you'd have to figure out how to get `P(C | AB)` from what you have.